# Vagrant alternative to Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant, virtualbox

My company has decided to migrate our base server images from Ubuntu Server to Amazon Linux. In the past we would spin up an Ubuntu Server LTS box from [vagrantbox.es](http://vagrantbox.es/) to emulate an instance in our AWS stack, but Amazon only provides an AMI.

According to the [Amazon Linux AMI FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/), updates are custom tailored depending on the EC2 region the AMI is launched in, which might have issues with [exporting an AMI to VDI](https://www.geekandi.com/2014/03/22/amazon-linux-to-vagrant-box/). I've also read that Amazon Linux removes a lot of cruft from RHEL and Fedora to make it a server-optimized distribution.

1. How can I emulate Amazon Linux in an environment where I might not have a persistent network connection?
2. Apart from switching to `yum`, what pitfalls should I expect in running Amazon Linux locally?
3. Is there some pre-built vagrant box for Amazon Linux that gets around these pitfalls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon does not provide an image of its distribution for use on other VM platforms. You may find [these](https://www.geekandi.com/2014/03/22/amazon-linux-to-vagrant-box-part-1/) [blog](https://www.geekandi.com/2014/03/24/amazon-linux-to-vagrant-box-part-2/) [posts](https://www.geekandi.com/2014/04/13/amazon-linux-to-vagrant-box-part-3/) [useful](https://www.geekandi.com/2014/04/13/amazon-linux-vagrant-box-images/) though; they provide detailed instructions for building Amazon Linux disk images, and in the last article he provides direct links to images he built for VMWare and VirtualBox.

Amazon Linux is based on CentOS so you could also start there.

Comment: I included a link to that guy's set of posts as they pertain to vagrant, but I wasn't sure what pitfalls there might be in using his images. I'm looking for developer testimonials either for your suggestion or for alternatives I can use when working with Amazon Linux.

Comment: Main pitfall is that it's a lot of work to maintain them yourself. When Amazon Linux is patched or releases a new version, you're out of date. You could use the Vagrant AWS provider and just run your dev boxes on EC2 instances. That's what I do.

Comment: Ah shoot, then that defeats the purpose of developing locally with vagrant if I need an internet connection to test. Looks like building on top of CentOS is my best bet so far.